# Web API authorization process via HttpClient (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, client-server

I am working on combination of Web API application and desktop client program (WPF). I am using *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client* for a client-server HTTP communication and now I want to use authorization / authentication system of the server application to authorize user of the client program.

Point is, I want to use (=start with) the same HttpClient class, I would like to use ASP.NET Identity library on server side - call controller with credentials in HTTP header, receive actual token from server, keep it and than use it for authentication in other controllers where it is required.

I know the theory, some basic steps, but I have not found any useful and actual resource with a simple examples or tutorial how to do it well. Does anyone know about good resource to learn, how to do that?

Thanks a lot.